# how to attach canvas image in a mailto link?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mailto

I created a canvas image in my html page, and I want to create a mailto link, that when clicked on will open up the default email application (outlook for example) with the image of the canvas attached. Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

No. It's not possible to do this with a **"mailto:" link** (that I suppose is what you are asking for), due that **mailto: links do not support passing any kind of attachments** (files, data, whatever), only text content (Subject, message... )

Check it here: [RCF 2368](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html)

I think will be possible to do it sending the email from the server using a form, I mean send the canvas as DataURL to a PHP that could attach it to an email, and send that email with the attached file using **PHPMailer Class**. That's the only workaround I can figure out right now.

Greetz.
c:.

Answer (score -3):

Actually, you can easily create a "mailto" link to an image. (I think the first person misunderstood your question.)

The html looks like this. Just make sure to switch out the generic email and image info for yours.

```
 <a href="mailto:info@youremail.com">
  <img class="aligncenter" title="YOUR IMAGE TITLE" alt="Your ALT Image Title" src="http://www.example.com/image-file-location"/>
 </a>
```

Comment: Won't this just make a clickable image that opens the mail client. I don't think this will attach the image on the mail. The first person didn't misunderstand my question, as that is what I am asking (I am using another account here).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're the one who misunderstood. The question definitely is asking if it is possible to attach an image to the e-mail.