# HTML Email Tag with Image in Body

Tags: html, image, email, tags

I was wondering if someone might be able to help.

I know the email tag `mailto:someone@url.com` and I know to add a Subject to place `mailto:someone@url.com?subject=Hello`

What I want to do is place an image in the body of the email from a web link.

So when someone clicks the link an email is ready to write with an image in the body already?

Can this be done?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: (duplicate) similar question here-> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11887166/4916251

Comment: Thanks @Ninda So it looks like the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible.But you can add the link in content-part.

Just add the body parameter into the ever-growing list of parameters we are using.

```html
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com&bcc=lastperson@theirsite.com&subject=Big%20News&body=Body-goes-here">Email Us</a>
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, but a link is not what I need. I figured that it cant be done.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer. It's my first answer that has been accpeted.Will continue to share knowledge. @RenegadeRob